# Making different int incompatible, in Java, with no runtime cost

Tags: java, android, optimization

In my hypothetical grocery store app, I have integer quantities of apples and oranges.

Is there a pattern by which I can stop apples and oranges from being compared, added or subtracted at compile time, yet which will be optimised away?  (On Android 4+ and SDK 7+).

e.g.

```
public class Apples {
  final int count;

  public Apples(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public Apples add(Apples count) {
    return new Apples(this.count + count);
  }
  ...
}
```

Could/would something like the above be compiled or jitted away to simple integer arithmetic, with no heap allocations?

Comment: Why would someone like to compare apples and oranges?

Comment: There is no pattern that will be optimized away completely. A side note: It is certainly **not** sensible to apply this here, but *conceptually*, JScience from jscience.org went very far with handling this problem. They have structures for measurements, units and conversions (like http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/Measurable.html or http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/Unit.html ) that tackle exactly this problem.

Comment: @Aakash The point is to stop programmers accidentally comparing applies and oranges, at compile time.

Comment: With no heap allocations, I don't think something is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could/would something like the above be compiled or jitted away to simple integer arithmetic, with no heap allocations?

No.

Or at least, not with current generation JIT compilers.

And, I don't think there is any other solution that will do what you want; i.e provide type-safe quantities **without the overheads of objects and object allocation**.

Obviously, if you don't care about the overheads, your current approach will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pattern: just make them unrelated types, and the type system does the rest:

```
Apples a = new Apples(4);
Oranges o = new Oranges(5);
a.add(a);  // Fine.
o.add(o);  // Fine.
a.add(o);  // Compiler error.
o.add(a);  // Compiler error.

public final class Apples {
  final int count;

  public Apples(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public Apples add(Apples count) {
    return new Apples(this.count + count);
  }
}

public final class Oranges {
  final int count;

  public Oranges(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public Oranges add(Oranges count) {
    return new Oranges(this.count + count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hinting at in the code example.